# How to close the cd tray automatically every minute?

Tags: windows

I explain better:
On my workplace, all the dumb users has taken the wrong habit to leave the cd tray open forever on all computers...

Explain that they must close the tray, is just a waste of time: they say *"it is way more productive"*

There is a software that force-closes the tray automatically every minute?

Comment: Users can create some funny mythologies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the freeware utility [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) (NirSoft: [download zip file](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.zip)) and use Windows Scheduling to run this statement every minute:

```
 C:\Program Files\Wizmo\wizmo.exe cdrom close d:
```

(example)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if the exact tool actually exists, but [**here**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) is a small command-line utility that could be scheduled to run every 1-5-10-60 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, what harm does an open CD tray really do?

Of course, someone *might* break it, but then maybe he'll learn from this (at least if you take loooong to replace the broken drive).

On the other hand, closing the tray automatically will just annoy your user base. Why would you do this?

For me your request looks like child play: they don't wanna play your way, so you're looking for ways to make them by force.
Please. Grow up. Does it really hurt you if they leave the tray open?

The best peaceful solution: get slot-in-drives (Pioneer used to build there, dunno if they still do): No tray, no pain.

Comment: Slot-load drives aren't that common these days, except in Macs. Depending on the situation, if the desktop is on the floor, yes, they may break it very easily. And refusing to replace right away could cost your job because that user may be a "VIP" favorite of someone.

Comment: i would apply this solution just for a few weeks until they understand.
For example, last month, they was turning off the server (to save energy, they say) even if there was a "DONT TURN OFF" sticker on it. So, i disconnected the power button, and problem fixed.
Now i reconnected the power button, but they still think it won't turn on, so they won't even try to turn it on

Comment: Well, to me "until they understand" sounds more like "until I have it my way".  
It's your decision.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to post [this list](http://www.download32.com/eject-close-cd-freeware.html), but as NirCmd is already mentioned by 2 other guys, I suppose you better check that one out first ;-)

Comment: O_O so many programs

I didn't found so many by googling

Comment: A bit ashamed to admit it, but I found them using bing :s

Comment: Hahaha.  Bing.  S'ok, do what you need to get the job done :)

Comment: I had changed my default search provider for a while for the sake of... well you have to try it to be able to speak about it, don't you... and I must say... it only lasted for less than a day... I really think you need more than a 30m$ (or how much was it) campaign to out-perform google on relevance and especially on cleanly-ness (does that word even exist?). I really hate the look and feel... a picture on top of a search engine... WTF?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the CD players from their machines?

But a scheduled task could be very annoying. If the task happens to run right after the use has opened to tray to insert a cd... and the cd is halfway while the job closes the tray.... *clank* *crash*

Comment: yes it can be dangerous

Answer (score 0):

You can use this handy VBS.  I use it for ejecting a CD on my Vista-running-on-a-mac setup.  Guess it should work both ways

Const CDROM = 4
For Each d in CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").Drives
  If d.DriveType = CDROM Then
    Eject d.DriveLetter & ":\"
  End If
Next

Sub Eject(sDriveLetter)
  Dim ssfDrives
  Dim oShell
  ssfDrives = 17
  CreateObject("Shell.Application")_
    .Namespace(ssfDrives).ParseName(sDriveLetter).InvokeVerb("Eject")
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I second thijs' opinion.

Anyway, on linux machines you could **try** with `eject -t`. See man page. YMMV.

Ciao
--bronto

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the "windows" tag before posting :-(